# How do I create a floating tag that starts in a fixed position?

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

I would like to create a small DIV about width=200px and height=100px and make it somewhat transparent.

The DIV needs to be over a picture.  I would like the client to be able to drag around the DIV anywhere on the screen.

On initial page load, I need to the DIV to be placed in the same fixed position to start.

Does anyone have any jquery scripts that will do this?

thanks you.

Erik

Comment: JQuery UI draggable  http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quirky, but may give you a simple start. Hopefully others can pitch in! :)

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V3TQ9/

CSS (I didn't add the transparency)

```
<style type="text/css">

    #moveit {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:#666666;
    display:block;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="moveit"></div>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#moveit').mouseup(function(e){ 

        $('#moveit').css({ left : (e.pageX - 100) , top : (e.pageY - 25) });
        $('#moveit').off('mousemove');

}).mousedown(function(){  

        $('#moveit').on('mousemove', function(e){       
            $('#moveit').css({ left : (e.pageX - 100) , top : (e.pageY - 25) });
        });

});

</script>
```